# splitting screen into two halves horizontally

Tags: html, css

Could you please advise how to divide the screen into two halves horizontally? Here is my attempt, but the height=100% kind of doesn't work. (I intend the whole screen to be covered) How can I make it work? Thank you.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>hey I am a title</title>
    <style>
    .t7{width: 50%; height: 100%; background-color: #506970; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>


<div class=t7>aaa</div>

<div class=t7>bbb</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `height: 100%` means 100% of the parent. That also means, it needs a defiend height not a calculated to fit-content one. Use `height: 50vh` instead

Comment: Here is the [answer](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_split_screen.asp), but I think you should google your problem first before asking it here.

Answer (score 3):

Both the **html** and **body** tag should have their width and height properties set to 100%. By default the height won't be 100%, which is why these elements do not expand vertically. As a side note, you might also want to set the margin (specifically on the **body**) to zero.

Also, whitespace between elements can cause problems when you are trying to use up 100% of the width. And because you are using **div** elements, you will want to set their 'display' property to 'inline-block'. By default they use 'block', which causes a line break (effectively) after the element, so the two elements wouldn't be side-by-side.

Try this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>hey I am a title</title>
  <style>
    html, body { width: 100%; height: 100%; padding: 0; margin: 0; }
    .t7{width: 50%; height: 100%; background-color: #506970; display: inline-block; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

  <div class=t7>aaa</div><div class=t7>bbb</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

In this case you can use `vh` units for the screen height.
`vh` – Relative to 1% of the height of the viewport.

Your code will look like that:

**.html**

```html
<div class="top"></div>
<div class="bottom"></div>
```

**.css**

```css
.top, .bottom {
  height: 50vh;
}
```

As a result, the screen will be splitter in half horizontally.

Answer (score 2):

In order for the CSS `height` property to work using percentages, the parent element must have a defined height. So to fix this, you must git the `<body>` a height of 100%. But in order for that to work, you must also give the `<html>` a height of 100%.

```
html, body { height: 100% }
```

Another option is to use the viewport width/height `vw`/`vh` measurement instead of percentage based measurement.

```
.t7 { width: 50vw; height: 100vh; ... }
```